# Transformar Clase Java Exception a Json

Tags: java

Durante mucho tiempo he estado usando por ejemplo esta clase:

```
class Edu {
 private String nombre = "edu";
 private int edad = 20
}
```

Con sus getters setters,constructores etc.

Para imprimir esta clase o cualquier clase que usa mi aplicación siempre he usado este método y siempre ha funcionado correctamente -->

// Se recoge un Object.

```
private void showJsonInputOutput(Object obj) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        // Se convierte el obj a json para poder imprimirlo
        String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        log.info(jsonContent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // relanza el error
        this.showError("showJsonInputOutput() -->", e);
    }
}
```

La salida sería tal que así  `{"nombre":"edu","edad":20}`

Ahora lo que necesito es imprimir un objeto pero de tipo "Exception" HttpClientErrorException o HttpServerErrorException.

Supondría que el resultaría sería: `{"cause":"HttpClientErrorException", "detailMenssage": "404" ... etc }`

Pero en vez de obtener un JSON con todos los datos, como podía hacer con todas las clases que usa mi aplicación, estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
Revienta en -> writeValueAsString(obj);

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException["mostSpecificCause"])
```

Lo que necesito es que también se impriman en JSON las clases que son de tipo "Exception".
Gracias!

Comment: Dado que las excepciones son algo particular, ¿por qué no creas un método propio tipo `getExceptionAsJson(Exception e)` y dentro de él obtienes lo que te interese de la excepción, lo metes en un JSON y lo retornas desde ese método? Otra opción interesante tanto para tu clase `Edu`, como para esta o para cualquier otra, sería utilizar `Gson`. Ahí sólo tendrías un modelo de tu excepción personalizada y Gson te lo convierte a Json directamente sin más historias.

Comment: La clase HttpClientErrorException, al depurarla tiene un atributo llamado detailMessage, el cual, no tiene un getter. entonces cuando hago el "cast" a ese tipo de Exception no puedo recoger el valor.

Comment: Con mayor razón, a mi juicio, deberías tener tu propio método para el caso de las excepciones. Allí podrías verificar si se trata de esta u otra clase particular de excepciones. Por ejemplo, ella extiende de [`HttpStatusCodeException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpStatusCodeException.html), que sí tiene sus métodos getter, si es que no puedes obtener la propiedad directamente.